# Maintain sub-folder and files permission as in source: puppet

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache

I have configured a master- client setup for puppet. I have a complete project that I have to copy to agents. There are some scripts (executable) and some jars and some configuration files. Now When I copy copy project, all permissions are changed. I know I can user "mode" to set the permission but the problem is that it is applied to whole files i.e., all sub-folders and files in the given folder. What is the best way to maintain the all documents permission on client side as it was on source (master) side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`file`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/file.html) resource has the attribute [`source_permissions`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/file.html#file-attribute-source_permissions). So you could do something like this:

```
file { '/some/where':
    ...
    source_permissions => 'use', # or 'use_when_creating'
}
```